# Как красиво преобразовать строку в список словарей на Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Имеется строка:

```
a = "[{'domain': '.google.com', 'expiry': 157282}, {'domain': '.google.com', 'httpOnly': False}]"
```

Пожалуйста подскажите как мне преобразовать это к списку словарей? =) Я могу это сделать регулярным выражением, но думаю есть более красивый способ. Заранее большое спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

можно воспользоваться безопасным [ast.literal_eval()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)

```
In [2]: import ast

In [3]: ast.literal_eval(a)
Out[3]:
[{'domain': '.google.com', 'expiry': 157282},
 {'domain': '.google.com', 'httpOnly': False}]
```

также можно воспользоваться модулем [yaml](https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation):

```
In [6]: import yaml

In [7]: yaml.safe_load(a)
Out[7]:
[{'domain': '.google.com', 'expiry': 157282},
 {'domain': '.google.com', 'httpOnly': False}]
```

или [json.loads()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads), если речь идёт о "валидном" JSON - в вашем случае это не так,т.к. JSON ожидает двойные кавычки.

NOTE: [не используйте `eval()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice)

Comment: Хм... Элегантно. Круть. Однако в документации сказано следующее **Warning It is possible to crash the Python interpreter with a sufficiently large/complex string due to stack depth limitations in Python’s AST compiler.** Не думаю, что это лучшее решение, хоть и самое простое

Comment: Большое спасибо! Наверное и правда есть смысл просто все обрабатывать в JSON формате по возможности. Я об этом не задумался =)